# Is there a tool or site where I can see wind vectors overlaid on a prognostic chart?

Tags: weather

I'm hoping to find a source where I can see wind vectors overlaid on a prognostic chart, to visualize how the wind moves around the pressure systems and fronts.

Curious if anyone knows of illuminating and fun weather data visualizations e.g.
https://earth.nullschool.net

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would probably be better on [Earth.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Apart from being probably off-topic, the first part of this message feels like spam to me

Comment: @Federico: not spam. Search that like in Google?

Comment: @Ron Beyer this IMO would be a very helpful resource for pilots

Comment: regarding what Ron Beyer said, we already had this discussion (https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3215/1467 ) the outcome was: if the aviation aspect it is not prominent, it is off-topic.

Comment: I like www.windy.com

Answer (score 1):

Most pilots here in the states get their weather data from NOAA (The national weather service) you can find all of [their charts on their site here](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/outlook_tab.php).

Localized aviation weather is usually reported out of airports and can be found via [their METAR's](https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar?gis=off).

For visualization apps like [Foreflight](https://foreflight.com/) and [Garmin Pilot](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/115856) allow certain overlaying of data onto a map (these are however paid services).